Should I average data for agglomerative hierarchical clustering (AHC)?
I was conducting an experiment where I measured the response of wheat cultivars to pathogen inoculation. The experiment was repeated three times, with two reps each time. Two disease parameters were always measured. I wanted to perform AHC to divide the cultivars into clusters based on their level of response, but my question is: Should the data from all the reps be averaged before performing AHC, leaving only two datasets (one for each disease parameter)?
